# What is a difference using 'def something(request)' and 'class something(CreateView) in Django views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

As above, what is the difference between handling views like

```
def something(request):
    a = b.object.get()
    context = {
        'a' : a,
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

and

```
class something(CreateView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'template.html'
```

When I see tutorials, some use first, and some use second option. Which one is useful where and why?

Comment: A `CreateView` creates objects, whereas your function displays something. The `CreateView` will define a view for the GET and the POST method and handles these by reusing parts of the logic.

Comment: Class-based views already implement a lot of functionality that would normally repeat in every view, you can extend them, you can easily add mixins, integrate with forms etc. In general it's best to use CBVs unless you need a really simple view. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: Thanks. How do I get variables like above in context, where I do a = object and then pass it into context in CBVs?